# Unfixable Errors in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, should.js

I am writing a blogging platform and everything works wonderfully when tested on a web server. However, I am trying to write unit tests using Mocha and Should.js and I am coming across errors where there shouldn't be errors. For example, in the following code, whenever I try to actually add something to the callback function (3rd parameter), like calling `done()` or stating something like `fakeReq.entries.should.exist`, I get a million errors:

```
describe("#load()", function(done){
    entries.load(fakeReq,fakeRes,function(){},"my-first-post")
})
```

and here is what the function looks like:

```
exports.load = function(req,res,next,slug){
    var User = mongoose.model('User')
    Entry.load(req.param('year'), req.param('month'), slug, function (err, article) {
        if (err) return next(err)
        req.article = article
        next()
    })
}
```

However, leaving it like this makes it seem like nothing ever gets tested. From my command line (note that the above lines of code are in `Entries`):

```
Entries
  #show()
    ✓ should render something 

EntrySchema
  #from_fake
    ◦ should have a title: TEST
    ✓ should have a title 
    ◦ should have a slug: test
    ✓ should have a slug
```

Does anyone have a lot of experience with Mocha that can help me out? I don't think I can simply access Mongo with a `before()` or `beforeEach()` statement because part of the test is making sure my code accesses the database correctly.

Comment: I don't have experience with mocha, but what is `done` in `describe()` and do you need to call it?

Comment: maybe you should pass `done` in as the third parameter to `exports.load()` so when you call `next` within `exports.load()` it actually invokes mocha's `done`

Comment: @plato i tried that. if i put ANY function other than a blank dummy function as my third parameter it throws a million errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `it` function for your actual tests. `describe` it to describe a group of related tests and then calls to `it` within the `describe` callback are the actual tests.

```
describe("my module", function () {
  it("should require OK", function () {
      require("../my-module").should.exist
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was calling `it()` in my callback function instead of outside the function and that's why it wasn't working... I think. I'll definitely be back here if I run into more issues though :)